# Can I refer a drl file from a different drools projects?

Tags: drools

Currently I have a requirement whereby I have a common set of drl files in a Drools project in eclipse and some other DRL files requires to refer these, especially process flows. Is it possible?

For Ex, I have ProjectA having a process flow called Process1.bpmn
Process1.bpmn need to refer Rule1.brl in ProjectB

Is this possible? I have this scenario because I'm migrating from ILOG and I wanted to retain the same projects in ILOG.

For example I have the Test1.drl in ProjectA Test1.drl

```
   package com.mycompany.drools.types

   declare CheckVariable isCheckVar : boolean end
```

I have Test2.drl in ProjectB

```
    package com.mycompany.drools.rules

    import com.mycompany.drools.types.CheckVariable;

    rule "Hello World" then 
         System.out.println( "Hello "); 
    end
```

Im getting below errors:

```
    Rule Compilation error: Only a type can be imported.
        com.mycompany.drools.types.CheckVariable resolves to a package 
        Error importing : 'com.mycompany.drools.types.CheckVariable'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as soon as project B is in the class path of project A, you should be able to access to its resources.

Comment: How are you trying to access it? That's definitely the problem

Comment: For example I have the Test1.drl in ProjectA


Test1.drl
<br/>

package com.mycompany.drools.types
<br/>
declare CheckVariable
 isCheckVar : boolean
end
<br/>

<br/>   
I have Test2.drl in ProjectB
<br/>
package com.mycompany.drools.rules
<br/> 
import com.mycompany.drools.types.CheckVariable;
<br/>
rule "Hello World"
   then
        System.out.println( "Hello ");
end
<br/>


Im getting below errors:

Rule Compilation error: Only a type can be imported. com.mycompany.drools.types.CheckVariable resolves to a package
Error importing : 'com.mycompany.drools.types.CheckVariable'

Comment: You have duplicated definitions then.. that's not supported. I recommend you creating an extra drl file with all the imports (common things) and making sure that you add that drl once.

Comment: How to add to the classpath?